# PHP, Convert any number to float 0.x

Tags: php

I need to do this rather strange thing, let's say i have:

```
$number = rand(1, 9);
```

(This is just an example of what number it could be, in reality i get it in entirely different way)

And now i need "convert" that number to `0.2` or whatever number i got, basically it has to begin with 0 and be a `float` type of number.

Comment: Will the input always be between 1 and 9?

Comment: I hope that made you feel good, Linas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP does not support explicit type casting in variable declaration.  To convert the `int` to a `float` in the way you want to simply divide by 10:

```
$number = rand(1, 9) / 10;
```

See this page on [PHP Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) for more info.  If you mix `floats` and `ints` or other types they will be re-casted.  Exmple:

```
echo 10 + 2.5; // gives you 12.5, a float because of the types used
```

**Edit:** PHP does have explicit [type casting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting), just not in variable declaration.  But even if you cast an integer as a float, it won't display with a decimal place.  To do that use PHP's [`number_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function instead:

```
echo number_format(10, 1); // gives you 10.0
```

**Edit 2:**  If you simply want to make your number a decimal between 0 and 1 (such that 2 becomes 0.2, 25 becomes 0.25, etc.) you could use the following function:

```
function getNumAsDecimal($num) {
    return ($num / pow(10, strlen((string)$num)));
}
```

So `getNumAsDecimal(2)` would return `0.2`.

Comment: -1 PHP has explicit type casting, similar to C++ type casting.

Comment: Edited for clarity.  I meant that it didn't support it in variable declaration.

Comment: @Tiberiu-Ionuț_Stan, PHP explicit typecasting does not work (-1). Operators & such override, especially with numerics. Behold how explicitly cast strings automatically become floats:

echo (string) '6584987987987897987987978987897' == (string) '6584987987987897987987978987896' ? 'true' : 'false'; // returns true

Comment: The comparison operator is doing a  conversion before comparing. Type casting worked just fine. Try the === operator. Also, echo on booleans outputs '' ;)

Answer (score 0):

$number=(float)rand(1, 9)/10;

See PHP type casting.

Comment: > This is just an example of what number it could be, in reality i get it in entirely different way

Comment: My answer is identical to all the other answers. I was also the first. Yet a moderator deleted my comments prolly for rudeness, but left the "you didn't read the question" comment. What am I still doing on SO? Could someone please ban me already?

Answer (score 0):

```
function Floatize(){
    return (float) (rand(1, 9) / 10);
}

echo Floatize(); // will return something like 0.2 or 0.5 or 0.9
```